# Edge cases in reversal of votes

Tags: support, reputation

I lost 170 reputation due to [vote correction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) today, it makes sense and I expect to loose about 150 more soon, but it made me think about what would happen in some (hypothetical) cases.

**First case: I got 200+ reputation due to upvotes the day of the serial voting**
I got 17 upvotes due to "Serial Voting" and 10 regular ones, this would give me a total of 270 reputation, the daily limit is 200, so I only got +200 that day.
Would the vote correction remove 170 reputation, or only 100?

**Second case: I get 200+ reputation on the day of the "vote correction"**
I lost 170 reputation due to "vote correction", but then I get 25 upvotes on some of my answers.
Do I get the cap of 200 reputation, so +30 reputation for today, or do I get 250 reputation for 25 upvotes, giving me a total of +80 reputation for today?

**Third case: I decide to use all of my reputation for bounties, before the vote correction**
I have 1001 reputation after receiving 170 reputation due to serial voting and decide to start 2 bounties worth 500 reputation each, so now I have a reputation of 1.
The vote correction should remove 170 reputation, but I don´t have enough left, because my "[reputation can never drop below 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)".
Do those who receive the bounty get to keep it? Does the bounty get refunded and then the 170 reputation detracted, even though "[All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)"? Are 170 reputation removed from one of the bounties? Does the vote correction get canceled and I effectively added 170 reputation to the system?

**Fourth case: I earn a badge due to a vote that is removed in the vote correction**
The [revival badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/198/revival) requires you to have at least 2 upvotes on an answer.
I have 1 real vote and 1 due to serial voting, I get the badge and then one vote is removed by the system.
What happens with the badge?

The fourth case has likely actually happened to me both [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349088/#352125) and [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/347661/#352109), it looks like I can keep the badges though (Feel free to remove them if you are authorized to do so)

Comment: Possible reasons for downvotes: 1. it sounds like you know you've been serial upvoted which could indicate you are running a sockpuppet account (not saying you are though of course). 2. Learning how this stuff works could make it easier for people with socks to gain reputation from their socks which people like to avoid for obvious reasons.

Comment: That said the reversed rep probably only gets removed when those upvotes give you rep. So if you get serial upvoted 5 times before the cap and 5 times after it will reverse all the upvotes but only 5 will make you lose rep. (Only a gut feeling of mine... there is potential that you lose rep from all of them).

Comment: In the fourth case usually you would keep the badge as only tag badges can be lost. However, as it was down to serial voting the specifics may be different.

Comment: I got 17 upvotes within 11 minutes on jun 10th, between 20:09 and 20:20, so it´s pretty obvious that it is a case of serial voting. I also have 14 on june 13th between 21:45 and 21:55 plus one at 20:20, which may be part of it, but I am unsure, because there are 25 minutes between that vote and the first of the other 14. I can view this here (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/232393/mr-bear?tab=reputation), I don´t know if that link works for anyone else though

Comment: FWIW you didn't cap in either case so any vote reversal will reverse all the rep as you expect. When I expect I am getting serial voted on (in either case) I generally just flag for the mods and explain this. They have some tools to investigate but the votes are still anonymous, however, they can raise it to the SE team to look at who can see who voted.

Comment: My question was more for hypothetical cases, I am aware that none of them (except for the 4th) apply to me. The second one may still happen, and I will try to flag it for the mods, I am not sure how to, but I will figure it out.

Comment: To flag pick any post (best pick one that's part of the serial voting) and explain you were upvoted on days X and Y and for them to investigate to reverse them if fraudulent, Linking to this meta might help as well.

Comment: For the second case you will get +30 rep. I believe the reversal actually takes place on the day the votes were made but the event shows on the day the reversal happens. So for that day you earn 200 rep but it only shows +30 due to the event showing there. Evidence: I've had this happen a few times on SFF, for example, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOUWQ.png).

Comment: I have now flagged this (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352160/232393) answer, I did not link to this meta, as it doesn´t actually discuss my situation, I was simply curious, what would happen in some specific situations if they occur.

Comment: If you actually know the answer, then you might as well write an answer instead of a comment. If you want to talk more, then we should probably talk in one of the chat rooms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95003/discussion-between-thelethalcarrot-and-mr-bear).